# How to configure Kubernetes "docker on docker" using containerd on Azure

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, docker-in-docker, containerd

We need to migrate a configuration from Google Cloud Platform to Azure.

In GCP, we have Jenkins running in Kubernetes. The Kubernetes worker nodes run on [Container-Optimized OS with containerd](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-images#cos-variants). This allows us to use the Docker daemon running on the Kubernetes Worker nodes for running docker commands inside the pipelines (themselves running inside docker containers).

To have access to the Docker Dameon, we configure our containers as this:

```
- name: docker
  image: docker:1.11
  command: ['cat']
  tty: true
  env:
    - name: TZ
      value: America/New_York
  volumeMounts:
    - name: dockersock
      mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
```

When trying to do the same on Azure, we did not find something similar to [Container-Optimized OS with containerd](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-images#cos-variants) so there is no daemon running on the Kubernetes worker nodes. Therefore, we are getting te error "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?" inside the pipeline.

Is there a way to have a similar configuration to run docker-on-docker in Azure? more specifically, is there a way to configure the Kubernetes Worker nodes similar to [Container-Optimized OS with containerd](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-images#cos-variants)?